# Why does this multithreaded sample program not work?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

This is a minimal python program that is supposed to set a sentinel flag in one thread, and have that sentinel read and acted upon in another thread.

Some caveats:

1. It's minimal. I've omitted mutexes, thread safety etc
2. I've used a horrible global variable to share state. The real program will pass a shared class around

The program creates a generator thread that invokes a method on an instance of ClassA   that will set the sentinel variable on the global status holder (gStatusHolder) to True on a periodic basis

A listener is launched on a separate thread that calls the listener method. This method periodically checks the global sentinel variable for True and prints a message if it is and sets it back to false

The SetSentinel method does set the global flag to True periodically, but that is never detected in the listener method. The value of gStatusHolder.sentinelFlag is always false.

In the debugger I can see the sentinel variable being set to True in SetSentinel(), but after that when I set a breakpoint in the listener method the sentinel variable's value is false.

I have checked the object addresses of the gStatusHolder in SetSentinel() and listener() and, of course, they are the same.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock


class StatusHolder:
    sentinelFlag = False

gStatusHolder = StatusHolder()

class ClassA:
    def SetSentinel(cls):
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
            gStatusHolder.sentinelFlag = True
            print("Did you hear that?")


def generator(Alist):
    Alist.SetSentinel()


def listener():
    while True:
        if gStatusHolder.sentinelFlag:
            print("I heard!")
            gStatusHolder.sentinelFlag = False
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    listenerThread = Process(target=listener)
    listenerThread.start()

    A = ClassA()
    generatorThread = Process(target=generator, args=(A,))
    generatorThread.start()

    while(True):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Use [`multiprocessing.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event)? Your "sentinel flag" looks like attempt to reimplement Event exactly. When you share a class between processes, you get two copies of that instance, tey do not point to one memory location and are not aware of each other. To share smth between processes, use `multiprocessing.Manager`.

Comment: And please stop calling processes threads. Thread-based and process-based parallelism are entirely different concepts in python.

Comment: Did you intend for these to be threads? If not, sharing state between two subprocesses can be complicated. For instance, each process could pass data back to its parent which would do the combined work.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to see the flag being set to true if you are debugging the parent process. Any changes would be in the subprocess only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `multiprocessing` module, each process' memory is separate - they don't directly share variables or objects. Each process is a separate instance of the Python interpreter - thus the difference between the `multiprocessing` module and threads, and so the memory of the program is isolated.

Thus, both the `generator` and the `listener` processes in your code have their own copy of the `gStatusHolder` object.

Try using `multiprocessing.Value`, passing the same parameter to share objects across code (inter-process communication), or consider switching to threading if you don't need the features of `multiprocessing`

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Value


class ClassA:
    def SetSentinel(self, sentinelFlag):
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
            sentinelFlag.value = True
            print("Did you hear that?")


def generator(A, sentinelFlag):
    A.SetSentinel(sentinelFlag)


def listener(sentinelFlag):
    while True:
        if sentinelFlag.value:
            print("I heard!")
            sentinelFlag.value = False
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    sentinelFlag = Value('b', False)

    listenerThread = Process(target=listener, args=(sentinelFlag,))
    listenerThread.start()

    A = ClassA()
    generatorThread = Process(target=generator, args=(A, sentinelFlag))
    generatorThread.start()

    while(True):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: _The real program will pass a shared class around_ - this will make it more complicated than a smiple flag.